# Selling merchandise inside game?

Tags: unity, monetization, plugin, commercial

I am developing my first iOS game on Unity. I spent a lot of time creating beautiful artwork for the game (characters and scenery). I gave testflight access to my friends and advisors, and they loved the game art, and asked me if I have ever thought about selling t-shirts or something.

I did some research, and found three services offering a SDK or plugin that lets me sell merchandise inside the game:

[themonetizr.com](http://themonetizr.com)
[merch.amazon.com](http://merch.amazon.com)

First I thought about using Amazon, but then I saw that the monetizer actually lets players buy right inside the game (which is nice, as I would hate users to be directed to their browser) and they a lot more products, like phone cases.

Have you guys used any of these services before? How hard are they to integrate?

Thanks!

Comment: This does seem to be a rather broad question to be asking and the last one is opinion-based in my opinion

Comment: This type of informal poll of developers might be more at home on a discussion forum like GameDev.Net or a social media network like Twitter. "How hard is a _____ to integrate?" isn't really a question that has a correct verifiable answer, as the experience likely varies substantially from one developer or project to another.